# There are 3000 students each taking exactly 4 courses and there are 803 courses being offered. How big could the smallest class be?

Tags: combinatorics

My attempt would be to multiply 3000 x 4 = 12,000 and then divide it by 803 which results in 14.9 rounded up to 15. So the smallest class can have 15 students. I'm not sure if this is right because supposedly this is to be done with the Pigeonhole Principle.

Comment: If all students decide NOT to take a specific course, then the minimal number would be $0$. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would round down tho. If the smallest is $15$ then you would have a minimum of $12045$(so you registered twice the student in the same class) registrations and you only have $12000$. The Pigeonhole Principle is implicit in the computation in the sense that if you want to prove that $14$ is optimal then if you take $15$, at least one student is registered twice in the same class but this is not possible.

Comment: Ah you mean use the floor function on 14.9 to make it 14.

Comment: 14 x 803 = 11,242

Comment: @usukidoll Yes, because the equation is like $803x\leq 3000\times 4$